# email validation in multiline textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have a multiline textbox in which i will be entering many email addresses.
how to validate email address at client side for multiple email address. i have used RegularExpressionValidator for validating email in textbox.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply extend the Validator with a loop. Split the textbox string into a array of emails and validate each. In that loop you can feed another array to later screen all wrong emails or abort at the first failed validation.

Something like this:

```
var mails = textboxcontent.split(';'); // you can also split by blanks. You may also consider the use of trim(str) -> see example below

for(var i = 0, len = mails.length; i < len; i++){
    // check mails[i]
    if(false)
        alert();
}

// or

var failed = '';
for(var i = 0, len = mails.length; i < len; i++){
    // check mails[i]
    if(false)
        failed += mails[i] + ' ';
}
```

Custom trim implementation (jQuery has a own one if you use it)

```
function trim (str) {
    return str.replace (/^\s+/, '').replace (/\s+$/, '');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try defining a delimitor which separates emails in the multiline textbox (like ';') and create a regular expression according to the new syntax.

**Or**

You can read the content of the multiline textbox, split the emails and put the strings in an array or list and validate each one separately.